# Error importing matplotlib except when using anaconda

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu, pip, anaconda

I've been trying to run a program on my computer that uses matplotlib, but whenever I run it, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

So far, I have tried installing it via:

```
pip install matplotlib
pip3 install matplotlib
python3 -m pip install matplotlib
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

The only way it manages to work is if I install it through anaconda, but after I uninstall it, it starts showing the error message again. I am using Ubuntu, and I have edited my .bashrc file to contain these lines:

```
export PYTHON=python3
alias python=python3
```

What could be the reason that anaconda is the only solution? And why doesn't it continue to work after it's uninstalled?

Comment: Have you tried `python3 -m pip install matplotlib`? If so, could you attach the output of that to your question.

Comment: It outputs that the requirements are already satisfied, and I get the same ImportError.

Comment: How about `easy_install matplotlib`

Comment: Do you have 2 versions of Python on your machine?

Comment: I think Ubuntu by default comes with python 2.7, but most of the time people use python 3. Therefore yes, most people do have 2 versions of python.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following:

From terminal run:

```
python3 -m pip install matplotlib
```

If that doesn't work try from terminal:

```
easy_install matplotlib
```

If that also doesn't work, then try opening the python interpreter (`python3` in terminal) and run the following in the python interpreter:

```py
import pip
pip.main(["install","matplotlib"])
```

Comment: "easy_install matplotlib" outputted "easy_install: command not found"

Comment: @Brandon could you tell me what version of ubuntu are you using.

Comment: I'm running 20.04

Comment: could you try ```sudo apt install python3-setuptools && sudo python3 -m easy_install install pip && python3 -m pip --version```